# BioBert for raw unlabeled text data

Tags: python

I would like to know how to use BioBert https://github.com/dmis-lab/biobert.

The problem is that they do not really go through how to use BioBert for RAW/Unstructured Unlabeled data.

I have an abundance of text that, from which I want to extract entities. It supposed to be easy to use the model as inference, however it is not!

Thats all thanks!

Comment: Not sure that StackOverflow is the place to request documentation.  Perhaps try and, when you get stuck, post a specific question.

Comment: I am aware of that :) I also asked at Biobert github repo and the author recommended https://bern.korea.ac.kr/. However, I am not looking for a workaround to be honest. I was looking the process to convert raw unlabeled text to conll2003 since that is the format that biobert uses! Then my aim is to fine-tune the model and get a brand new domain specific model!